# How to add item in select dropdown by button click event

Tags: reactjs

I have an bootstrap select dropdown control in react js application.I would like to know how to add item (input text control)in dropdown when I click on button.Please check my below code and advise how to do this..

initial state:-

```
this.state = {
    DivisionState: [],
    DivisionName :''
 };
```

loading item in dropdown:-

```
componentDidMount() {

  axios.get(ConfigItem[0].APIPath+'Menus/P')
   .then(res => {
    this.setState({DivisionState:res.data.data});
 })
```

This is an button click event by adding item in dropdown :-

```
addDivisionHandler = () => {
 // here I would like to know how to add item by button click 
 // for example, I need to add input text value (divisionname in dropdown)
}
```

html render:-

```
render() {

let DivisionList = this.state.DivisionState.length > 0
    && this.state.DivisionState.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <option key={i} value={item.MenuId}>{item.MenuName}</option>
  )
}, this);
return (
<select name ="ParentId" 

{DivisionList}
</select> 

<input type="text" name ="DivisionName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtDivision" placeholder="Division" value={this.state.DivisionName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
<Button type="button"  size="sm" color="success"onClick={addDivisionHandler } ><i className="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Add Division</Button>
```

Comment: Something like `thie.setState({ DivisionState: [...this.state.DivisionState, this.state.DivisionName] });` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your addDivisionHandler would look something like this:

```
addDivisionHandler = () => {
  this.setState(prev => ({
    DivisionName: '',  // Resets input back to empty
    DivisionState: [...prev.DivisionState, { MenuId: prev.DivisionName, MenuName: prev.DivisionName }] // Add value of DivisionName to list of DivisionState
  });
}
```

Comment: I have check above code,but DivisionName is adding empty string in dropdown

Comment: Edit: Original code was adding the string to the array instead of the expected object format. Here is a working Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-lederberg-7s8vf?file=/src/App.js